# noarch RPM with dependecies: i586 vs x86_64

Tags: dependencies, rpm, opensuse

I built an empty RPM which depends on all software we need for a server.

This RPM is "noarch" at the moment.

If I try to install it I get this message:

```
LANG=C zypper install foo-server
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: foo-server-1.0-1.noarch requires netpbm, but this requirement cannot be provided
     uninstallable providers: netpbm-10.61.1-2.1.1.i586[oss]
                   netpbm-10.61.1-2.1.1.x86_64[oss]
 Solution 1: deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install foo-server-1.0-1.noarch
 Solution 3: do not install foo-server-1.0-1.noarch
 Solution 4: break foo-server-1.0-1.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

Is it possible to provide a default for the archictecture (64 vs 32)?

My RPM just requires "netpbm" without any version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose option 1: deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts and everything worked. I tried to find what "patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts" is, but couldn't find a good solution ...